# a single face in an object is shiny in solid mode and showing a strange gradient color in render

Tags: modeling, nurbs-surface

This is a door that I'm making. There is nothing special about it. It somehow has one face (A) that is different than others. I've tried flipping the normal, deleting the face and remaking the face. I also checked the vertex positions. Not sure what else to check.

I might end up deleting this whole A side and use extrude from the other side to recreate the door. But I would like to know what caused it so I can avoid it next time. Thanks.

[image: This face is different than others.]

[image: The opposite side face is normal like all the others.]

Comment: That face is an ngon, but that alone should cause the shading to differ.. Do you still have a copy of the old mesh? Perhaps it was slightly non-planar or something.

Comment: The other side is exactly the same as an ngon, but did not have this condition. I've delete this A side completely and extrude from the other side and the problem disappeared. I'm sure it's something I did, just don't know what!

Comment: I'd suspect double vertices, but it sounds like you checked for those. Without a file to inspect, I don't think there is much we can do.

Comment: You were right! I found an extra vertex so close to the one next to it that I missed. So my question now is, other than using the removing double vertices feature, what else can I do to make sure there is no loose ones without zoom all the way in to find individual ones? Thank you so much.

Comment: You can probably use the "Dissolve vertex" option(at bottom of menu when pressing x)

Comment: @fuzzcats Increasing Remove doubles search radios could help you find vertices like these.

Comment: Thanks Naioai Studios. I'll do that next time when I clean up my models. @RegusMartin I see merge distance when I did the remove doubles, is this the same thing?

Comment: @fuzzcats Yes, that is the option I was talking about.

Comment: @RegusMartin Thanks, I've never tried to adjust that before. I'll try that next time.